# How to check an associative array for all null values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, excel

This is probably a very trivial question, but please bear with me.

I am trying to read a lot of data into an array of associative arrays. The data contains a lot of empty arrays and arrays with keys set and but all null values. I want to ignore those and only push arrays with at least one key mapped to a non-null value. (The data comes from an excel sheet and it has lots of empty cells that are registered as "set" anyway.) So far I have tried:

> if(!empty(${$small_dummy}))
>     array_push(${$big_dummy}, ${$small_dummy});

That gets rid of the empty arrays but not the ones where all keys map to null. Is there a better way to do this than looping through the entire array and popping all null values?

Comment: If you convert it to a .csv file i think you might have more luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the code you have already, you can change:

```
if(!empty(${$small_dummy}))
```

to:

```
if(!empty(array_filter(${$small_dummy})))
```

That will filter out all empty values (values evaluating to `FALSE` to be precise) and check if the resulting array is empty. Also see the manual on [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/array_filter).

Note that this would also filter `0` values so you might need to write a custom callback function for `array_filter()`.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing was that array_filter would not "return to a write context" according to the parser so I had to have it return to a variable and let the if statement evaluate that

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal approach, but `array_sum` will return 0 if all values can't be cast to a numeric value. So :

```
$small_dummy = array("a" => null, "foo", "", 0); 

if(array_sum($small_dummy) === 0)
```

would pass. But this is only the way to go if you are expecting the values to be numeric.

Actually, if the problem is that the array keys have values and therefor are not passing as `empty()`, the go with `array_values`:

```
if(!empty(array_values(${$small_dummy})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try if(!array_filter($array)) { also